# Call Stored Procedure on specific database with MVC Application connecting to 2 databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, stored-procedures

I have ASP.NET MVC application running with multiple database, one of which holding the stored procedures. My application along with stored procedure was working fine until I added another database connection string in web.config

`Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDbConnection" connectionString="xyz" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CIDDbConnection" connectionString="abc" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have stored procedure on `AppDbConnection`

Now I am getting error

> Could not find stored procedure 'GetAllFunction'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.  Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'GetAllFunction'.

C# Code calling stored procedure:

```
public List<GetAllFunction_SP_Map> GetAllFunction_From_StoreProcedure()
{
        List<GetAllFunction_SP_Map> query;

        using (var dbContext = new FunctionContext())
        {
            query = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<GetAllFunction_SP_Map>("exec GetAllFunction").ToList();
        }

        return query;
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
public class FunctionContext : BaseContext<FunctionContext>
{
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<App.DAL.Model.GetAllFunction_SP_Map> GetAllFunction_SP_Map { get; set; }
}
```

I have Data Access of two database in separate application folder and both have their `DbContext`

My question is how to solve this error, I believe somehow I need to tell in C# to use specific database from where I am calling the stored procedure.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a connection string would not cause this issue. I guess, what happened in addition to that, is your `FunctionContext` did get modified as well, to use the new connection string. Try this:

```
using (var dbContext = new FunctionContext("AppDbConnection"))
{
    query = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<GetAllFunction_SP_Map>("exec GetAllFunction").ToList();
}
```

... without knowing what else could have been modified.

Comment: I not suppose to pass data object directly in class as I am using Repository pattern along with UnitOfWork